# Getting and storing address of erc20 contract after dynamically creating it

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, mapping, constructor

I have a function which dynamically creates an ERC20 contract on calling a function in another contract as follows:

```
function createDao(string _tokenName) public payable {

  tokenNumberIndex = safeAdd(tokenNumberIndex, 1);

  string memory _tokenSymbol = 
         bytes32ToString(uintToBytes(tokenNumberIndex));

  address _tokenAddress = 
       (new REP).value(msg.value)(_tokenSymbol, _tokenName);

  erc20SymbolAddresses[_tokenSymbol] = _tokenAddress;

  proposalIndex = safeAdd(proposalIndex, 1);

  emit NewProposalCreated(proposalIndex);

  newProposalInternal(
    proposalIndex,
    _tokenSymbol, 
    _tokenName, 
    _tokenName,
    msg.sender,
    msg.value);    
}
```

I am confident that the following code is executing correctly:

```
address _tokenAddress = 
   (new REP).value(msg.value)(_tokenSymbol, _tokenName);
erc20SymbolAddresses[_tokenSymbol] = _tokenAddress;
```

However, `erc20SymbolAddresses` gives `0` address for all possible token symbols. How long does creation of rep take? How would I know if the creation fails?

REP Contract code is as follwing:

```
contract REP is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
string public symbol;
string public  name;
uint8 public decimals;
uint public _totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint) balances;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

constructor(string _tokenSymbol, string _name) public payable{
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
    name = _name;
    decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = msg.value;
    balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
}
 ..........
 ..........
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are calling the parameters wrong try using and not include the `msg.value` property, I don't see the benefit of including it in your particular contract.

```
address _tokenAddress = (new REP(_tokenSymbol, _tokenName);
```

There are a number of reference truffle boxes you can examine as well that have erc20 factories such as [EIP20Factory](https://github.com/Paperchain/nuxt-box/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20Factory.sol)